# Do animals with very small eyes see microscopic objects?

Tags: vision

I understand that many small creatures have very elementary eyes: they are not scaled-down versions of the human eye but as I understand it often just light-sensitive organs for detecting movement.

However, a mouse I would guess has an eye that is like the human eye but probably less than 1% the size. So does that mean that a mouse sees details that humans can't?

There has been recent evidence that ants might recognize their own reflections. Now, I know the structure of insect eyes is very different from mammalian eyes but if indeed they can recognize themselves in a mirror, that implies that their eyes can perceive very small details.

I could also imagine that things like wavelength mean that details of very small objects simply can't be perceived by bouncing visible light off of them -- that is why their are electron microscopes and so I could believe that mice, etc. can see bacteria, etc. any better than we can.